# Django REST Framework : ManyToMany relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on a Django project, I'm new at this and it's difficult to find clear documentation about this.

My issue is very simple, I want at the creation of my model, automatically associate another model through a ManyToMany relationship.

Here goes the code :

Model :

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False)
    estates = models.ManyToManyField(Estate, blank=True)
```

Serializer :

```
class FavoriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    estates = EstateSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Favorite
        fields = ['uuid', 'title', 'estates']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = super(FavoriteSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

ViewSet :

```
class MyFavoriteEstatesListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FavoriteSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Favorite.objects.filter(users__id=self.request.user.id)
```

I'm currently sending something like this through a POST :

```
{"title": "some title", "estate_uuid": "XXX"}
```

I just wanted to instantiate my Estate model with the UUID I just sent and adding it with

```
favorite.estates.add(estate)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you add your models?

Comment: You may have to go with a combination of context setters, as well as a nice little receiver.py...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
class EstateField(serializers.RelatedField):
   def to_representation(self, obj):
       return EstateSerializer(obj).data

   def to_internal_value(self, data):
       return Estate.objects.get(pk=data)

class FavoriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    estates = EstateField(many=True, queryset=Estate.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Favorite
        fields = ['uuid', 'title', 'estates']
```

I am using [**`Custom Fields`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) to represent the data as dictionary, but take input as `uuid`.

Comment: thank you @ruddra, it's working but, on reading, I have this error : `unhashable type: 'ReturnDict'`, looks like to_representation doesn't work

Comment: Um, does this work: `return EstateSerializer().to_representation(obj)`?